# How to highlight cells contains specific text in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have on my sheet many columns, so I want to highlight the cells on column A that contains a specific value. eg. I have on column A 200 rows, I want to highlight the CELLS that contains "2019" value. This is it and please keep in mind that I want to highlight not to change color.

Comment: what do you mean by highlight? can you provide example?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't upload photos but as example. go to google sheets and press CTRL + left click on the cell and again while you are pressing CTRL press on other cell. It's like selecting multiple cells to do action with, hope you got what I mean

Comment: I see now......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of action can't be done in Google Sheets other than manually holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and selecting cells of interest.